# Bootstrap 2 on IE10 displays Modal wrong

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

i have a problem with bootstrap 2.2.1 and have a big problems with my modals in IE10. 
When the modal opens it appears in the right top corner and the most of it is cutted of. 
See Screenshot. 
[image]

This appears only in IE10. 
Do you know why and can you help me?

I can't show you the site and link, because it's on a site where you need a account to use it.

EDIT - SOLUTION:
I found the solution! The modal loaded a php file and in this php file I loaded the header of the site again (the  area). And that was the mistake. After deleting the inculde line every thing worked.

Comment: disable the toolbar (it seems to be a third party like ask toolbar) in your browser and check. for more details go through this thread. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18998507/ask-toolbar-preventing-bootstrap-modal-to-show which I also faced the same issue.

Comment: hi thanks. but this wasn't the error. I tried it on a other computer without the ask toolbar and had the same error. 
Strange is also, after closing the modal the whole site layout is destroyed. Everything is on the left site.

Comment: it seems that you missed to close a div or any other tag. please close examin dom elements through developer tools F12 in ie

Answer (score 1):

IE 10 seems to behave this way when allowed to render in "quirks" or "compatibility mode"; use this meta tag to prevent it:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```